# How does one use the same model more than once with different names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Person class which I want to represent contributors such as chairs and vice-chairs of committees (and later, for other things).  So in my Committee class, I want to use the Person class to provide a chair and many vice-chairs:

- Committee has many ViceChairs
- Committee has one Chair

Chairs and ViceChairs are both People.

I expected to say

```
class Committee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vice_chairs, class_name: 'People'
    has_one  :chair, class_name: 'People'
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group, foreign_key: 'vice_chair_id'
    belongs_to :group, foreign_key: 'chair_id'
end
```

Is this the right approach?

**Update**: I have been advised to use [Single Table Inheritance](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) to solve this issue.  I changed my code like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Chair < Person
end

class ViceChair < Person
end

class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :type
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :affiliation

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Will this work? How do I write the migrations to support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A use case where you want slightly different behaviour based on the type of  model but where the attributes are the same, it is best to use Single Table Inheritance [1].

So I recommend the following:

**Models:**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vice_chairs
  has_one :chair
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end

class ViceChair < Person
  belongs_to :group
end

class Chair < Person
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**Migrations:**

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :type
      t.string :full_name
      t.integer :age
      t.references :group, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Example Usage:**

```
# create some test data
grp = Group.create!(name: "superheros")
vc = ViceChair.create!(full_name: "Superman Sam")
c = Chair.create!(full_name: "Batman Bob")
p = Person.create!(full_name: "Regular John Doe")

# add to group's ViceChairs
grp.vice_chairs << vc 

# add Chair to group
grp.chair = c
grp.save!

# Convert person to vice chair
p.type = "ViceChair"
p.save!
new_vc = ViceChair.where(full_name: p.full_name).first
grp.vice_chairs << new_vc
grp.vice_chairs.count
# => 2
```

**rails CLI commands:**

```
rails generate model Group name
rails generate model Person type full_name age:integer group:references:index
rails generate model ViceChair group:references --parent=Person
rails generate model Chair group:references --parent=Person
```

**Handling business logic of managing changes to Chair:**

You will need to add some custom logic to manage the Chair association without creating dangling chairs. I recommend adding an instance method to the Group class to `add_chair` and `remove_chair` then you need to decide what happens when a Person is removed from the chair position. They probably become an ordinary person. In which case you can set the type to `nil`.

Enjoy!

[1] More info on STI at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

If you have common fields with different model name, in that case you should use `Single Table Inheritance` just by adding a type field in the table. This field contains the model name.

You can refer the below link for Single table inheritance http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/